# Interleaving serialized data

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

With the following input file:

```
rohit
mohit
sohit
34
45
67
```

I have to create a new file with following:

```
rohit 34
mohit 45
sohit 67
```

**by only using paste & sed**. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: @İsmail ...  http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?paste

Comment: @Chris J, learning new things everyday, thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ paste -d' ' <(sed '3q' input.txt) <(sed -n '4,$p' input.txt)
rohit   34
mohit   45
sohit   67
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat input.txt
rohit
mohit
sohit
34
45
67
$ sed -e '/^[^0-9].\+/ d' < input.txt  | paste input.txt - | sed -e '/^[0-9]\+/ d'
rohit   34
mohit   45
sohit   67
```